# Spring Boot - configure Redis key-value store/cache

Tags: spring-boot, redis

Do I need to install Redis or run its instance before using spring-boot-starter-data-redis for sake of cache or key-value store (I am using gradle build tool)? Or does the autoconfiguration makes the embedded server ready to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need [Redis server](https://redis.io/download) installed in your machine in order start using it with Spring boot redis starters.